# dialogflow webhook not considering payload using fulfillmentText, fulfillmentMessages

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

**FULFILLMENT REQUEST**

```
{
  "responseId": "4955f972-058c-44c2-a9c6-fe2c1d846fcd",
  "queryResult": {
    "queryText": "dsnaf",
    "action": "intentNotMatched",
    "parameters": {},
    "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
    "fulfillmentText": "I think I may have misunderstood your last statement.",
    "fulfillmentMessages": [
      {
        "text": {
          "text": [
            "I'm afraid I don't understand."
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "outputContexts": [
      {
        "name": "****",
        "lifespanCount": 1
      }
    ],
    "intent": {
      "name": "****",
      "displayName": "Default Fallback Intent",
      "isFallback": true
    },
    "intentDetectionConfidence": 1,
    "languageCode": "en"
  },
  "originalDetectIntentRequest": {
    "payload": {}
  },
  "session": "****"
}
```

**FULFILLMENT RESPONSE**

```
{
  "payload": {
    "google": {
      "expectUserResponse": true,
      "richResponse": {
        "items": [
          {
            "simpleResponse": {
              "textToSpeech": "I'm sorry. I didn't quite grasp what you just said."
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "userStorage": "{\"data\":{}}"
    }
  },
  "outputContexts": [
    {
      "name": "***",
      "lifespanCount": 99,
      "parameters": {
        "data": "{}"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**RAW API RESPONSE**

```
{
  "responseId": "4955f972-058c-44c2-a9c6-fe2c1d846fcd",
  "queryResult": {
    "queryText": "dsnaf",
    "action": "intentNotMatched",
    "parameters": {},
    "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
    "fulfillmentMessages": [
      {
        "text": {
          "text": [
            "I'm afraid I don't understand."
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "webhookPayload": {
      "google": {
        "userStorage": "{\"data\":{}}",
        "richResponse": {
          "items": [
            {
              "simpleResponse": {
                "textToSpeech": "I'm sorry. I didn't quite grasp what you just said."
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "expectUserResponse": true
      }
    },
    "outputContexts": [
      {
        "name": "*****",
        "lifespanCount": 99,
        "parameters": {
          "data": "{}"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "******",
        "lifespanCount": 1
      }
    ],
    "intent": {
      "name": "****",
      "displayName": "Default Fallback Intent",
      "isFallback": true
    },
    "intentDetectionConfidence": 1,
    "diagnosticInfo": {
      "webhook_latency_ms": 286
    },
    "languageCode": "en"
  },
  "webhookStatus": {
    "message": "Webhook execution successful"
  }
}
```

**Google Assistance response**

> USER SAYS  dsnaf
>
> DEFAULT RESPONSE I'm afraid I don't understand.
>
> CONTEXTS
>
> _actions_on_google,initial_chat
>
> INTENT Default Fallback Intent

IN Google Assistance response is default fulfillmentText instead payload google richresponse

Answer (score 1):

Where are you testing this? If you're in the test console, it's always going to show you the simple text response. You'll need to specifically select Google Assistant in the test console to see the rich response for that platform:

[image: example animation]

Comment: Option is not available in my test console. In response section it is available.